# Java String replace issue

Tags: java, string

I have a code in which I am using replace method on Java String, but it is not working.. Please point out the mistake..

```
static String[] cavityMap(String[] grid) {
    String[] ans = grid;
    for(int i = 1; i<= grid.length-2; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j<= grid[i].length()-2; j++){
            int e = Integer.parseInt(grid[i].charAt(j) + "");
            int t = Integer.parseInt(grid[i - 1].charAt(j) + "");
            int b = Integer.parseInt(grid[i + 1].charAt(j) + "");
            int l = Integer.parseInt(grid[i].charAt(j - 1) + "");
            int r = Integer.parseInt(grid[i].charAt(j + 1) + "");
        if(e > t && e > b && e > l && e > r){
            ans[i] = ans[i].replace("X",(ans[i].charAt(j) + ""));
            System.out.println(ans[i].replace("X",(ans[i].charAt(j) + "")));
        }
        }    
   }    
   return ans;
}
```

The code execution is going in if conditional part.. But it is printing the same value as before.. Why is it not replacing the String with "X".. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Probably naming your variables in a better way would help.

Comment: Debug and/or unit-test.

Comment: I can't see what you're trying to achieve. Maybe give a little more context?

Comment: what is the input that is used?

Comment: have you tried loggin the these two values `ans[i].charAt(j)` and `ans[i]`

Comment: Sir I am passing a String[] array and need to replace it the strings contained in it with "X" if the condition in if statement is true.. The code execution implements inside of if statement 2 times

Comment: @JustLearning Sir How to log the values?

Comment: `ans[i].replace("X",(ans[i].charAt(j)))` is more easily written as `ans[i].replace('X', ans[i].charAt(j))` (note the single quotes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ans[i].replace("X",(ans[i].charAt(j) + ""))
```

will replace all occurences of `"X"` with `ans[i].charAt(j) + ""`.

If your intention is to replace `ans[i].charAt(j) + ""` with `"X"` you will need to swap your params:

```
ans[i].replace((ans[i].charAt(j) + ""), "X")
```

Also, using concatenation with empty string to cause conversion from `char` to `String` is discouraged. Consider explicitly invoking `Character.toString` or `String.valueOf`

```
ans[i].replace(String.valueOf(ans[i].charAt(j)), "X")
```

or better yet, since your replacement is a single `char`, just work in that type

```
ans[i].replace(ans[i].charAt(j), 'X')
```